# Multiple objects in same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have created a skills component that just has a name and corresponding img. Then I want to pass the skill.name into a child component. I'm trying to get 3 of these skills on the same row, but when I use the ngFor it puts each skill on it's own row.

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1 class="ui block header">
    Welcome to {{title}} WebApp!
  </h1>
</div>
<app-skills *ngFor="let listOfSkills of skillList" [skill]="listOfSkills"></app-skills>
```

skills.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h1>{{skill.name}}</h1>   
  <img src="assets/img/{{skill.name}}.jpg" alt="{{skill.name}} Badge" height="200" width="200">
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="showHide = !showHide">Show {{skill.name}} Stages</button>
  <app-stages *ngIf="showHide" [skill]="[skill.name]"></app-stages>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `display:inline` would help You?

Comment: No joy, I think the issue seems to be the code generated by the ngFor adds
    
    class="row"